# How can I change text size of button?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I need change text's size. How can I do it? Here is my code:

```
  let playAgain: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(140, 400, 100, 50))
  playAgain.setTitle("Play Again", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


  playAgain.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
  playAgain.tag = 1
  self.view!.addSubview(playAgain)
```

Comment: Having a UIButton is SpriteKit will not affect how you change the font. It is the same way in a single view application as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `titleLabel.font` property for your button.

```
playAgain.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
```

Comment: How to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change just the size of the font while keeping the font as it is, you may use this :

```
playAgain.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: playAgain.titleLabel.font.fontName, size: /*whatever size you like*/ )
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the font of a button you have to access the `titleLabel` property.

```
playAgain.titleLabel!.font = //... the font you want to use
```

This is explained in the docs for `UIButton`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/

Comment: @uzaylibeyb saying "it doesn't work" is useless. What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it crash? Does the font stay the same?  Does the phone explode when you try to run it? Explain what "doesn't work" means. Note, this code is directly from the Apple docs so if it "doesn't work" you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: You edited your answer. Before you edit, you didn't use "!". Still I thank you for your effort my friend.

Comment: @uzaylibeyb yes. I know. I realised my mistake. How much more difficult would it have been to explain what "doesn't work" means bough? It's the most useless analysis of any problem that it's possible to come up with. Also, are you telling me that you were unable to put a ! In? Really? Whatever.